# Smooch SDK implementation using Eclipse

Tags: android, chat, smooch

Smooch SDK implementation in Eclipse, crashes the app when i call `ConversationActivity.show(this)`

I'm using eclipse and `core-3.2.1-classes.jar` and `ui-3.2.1-classes.jar` in libs folder.
Please help

This is the crash report from logcat:

> Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field Smooch_inputText of type I in class Lio/smooch/ui/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.smooch.ui.R$id' appears in /data/app/chat.smooch.io.smoochchat-1/base.apk)

Answer (score 0):

I'll open by saying you'll save yourself many headaches by moving your project over to Android Studio. The ADT plugin for Eclipse [is no longer supported](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) and the Smooch Android SDK no longer officially supports Eclipse as of [version 3](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-android/releases/tag/3.0.0). The last release that included eclipse support was 2.3.1 (released on May 9th) The full Smooch SDK release history can be found [here](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-android/releases).

With that said, if you're truly stuck using Eclipse for other insurmountable reasons, you could try following these [Eclipse specific Smooch SDK instructions](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-docs/commit/26e052dbc2079dda20f1561fbc54bb23c6d4f3a3?short_path=da5a233#diff-da5a2331fbed9aa294714acea842ccc0) (which were removed from Smooch Android docs last month) however the obvious caveat here is you'll be stuck on the 2.3.1 Smooch SDK version.

Comment: The [previous revision](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-docs/blob/1e8daec702cd2ab9f5046b6a89b5242d75ff1051/source/includes/_adding_smooch_android.md) is easier to read than a changelog, but it's good to show it was removed

Comment: Thanks Andrew Lavers